# How to take inpur as ether?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapps, hardhat, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Suppose i have a function like these:

1. `function submit(address to, uint256 value) public {}`

- In case no. 1 i want to take the input of value as ether. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way to receive ethers, neither weis, is is only possible to receive an uint256, which is supposedly the quantity in weis. But if is specified that this quantity is in ethers, it can be converted to weis:

```
function submit(address to, uint256 valueInEthers) public {
    uint valueInWeis = valueInEthers  * 1 ether;  //1 ether == 1e18
}
```

Comment: So in my function's case value is in weis, but it is not msg.value, it is an uint. how it can be in wei??

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html): `msg.value (uint): number of wei sent with the message`. msg is a special variable, it is not possible to set it in ethers.

Comment: Remember, unit256 is just a variable which store an integer number, with the value expressed in weis